# Внешнее "Перенаправление" запросов к исполняющим файлам

Tags: windows

Моя `standalone` программа требует внешних `exe` файлов библиотек. Я бы их просто перенес в корень программы, но у их `dll`-ок идет коллизия имен.

Ни одну программу не декомпилировать.

Можно ли создать "ярлык" вместо абсолютного пути на относительный.

Чтобы при вызове к примеру, на `some_exe.exe`, этот ярлык отправлял вызов на файл в подпапке `dependencies/some_exe.exe`.

Работаю на `Windows`

Comment: в свойствах ярлыка есть "рабочая папка". ну либо симлинки если нужно в обратную сторону вывернуть.

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, можно просто использовать mklink из консоли

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]